# Using 'Tab' Key to move down one row

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have set-up multiple text fields with javascript

```
<input type=text name="<%=ID%>" value="<%=valueID%> > 

TextF11    TextF12   TextF13   TextF14
TextF21    TextF22   TextF23   TextF24 
TextF31    TextF32   TextF33   TextF34
```

When I fill-out TextF11 and press 'Tab' or 'Down arrow', I want system to focus TextF21.
Then TextF31.

Is there a way?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: Have you tried setting the tabindex.

Comment: @JosephSilber Silber I didn't mention the fact that this is in the display tag. When name is assigned, I tried to assign arrayID[i] = ID. And then if ID = TextF11ID is focused then I would search array and find arrayID[0]. Then onkeyup, I let system to focus arrayID[1]. However, as you see my method is very messy, I thought there must be a better way.

Comment: @dunli I have not, but that seems like what I am looking for. I will try that!